# Redirect if it's not certain user - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a page for a certain user in wordpress. Let's say his username is John. I am looking for PHP script that allow only 'John' to access that page and if users with different username other than 'John' tries to access the page they are redirected to another page.

I am new to PHP, so here's some code I have tried. But it redirects all users, even the user with username 'John'

```
<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
  $username = $user_info->user_login;
if ( $username=='John' ) {
echo '';
} else {
wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit;
}
?>
```

Here's a wordpress page with parameters to get userdata - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Comment: Is the username 'John' or 'john'?

Comment: @luweiqi It's  'John'

Comment: Try to `echo $username;` to see what it is

Comment: if @luweiqi answer worked then accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wp_get_current_user()` function instead.

```
global $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo();
$username = $current_user->user_login;

if ( $username == 'John' ) {
    echo '';
} else {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It's redirecting all users. I have double checked and the user with username "John" is getting redirected too!

Comment: @user6176114 Try to echo the `$username` variable

Comment: I tried to echo $username and it shows 'John'. So the username is definitely correct.

Comment: Thank you It worked now. I had to add this to your code

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem.

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
function blockusers_init() {
  global $current_user; 
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( 'John' == $current_user->user_login ) {
    //your desire page url
    wp_redirect( 'your page url' );
    exit;
  } else {
     wp_redirect( home_url() );
     exit;
  }
}
```

Take reference from

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
function blockusers_init() {
  if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) &&
 ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
 }
}
```

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/limit-access-to-your-wordpress-dashboard/

Comment: It's not working at all. Now it doesn't even redirect.

Comment: @user6176114 try it again, I have modified it .

Comment: can you explain your situation little better . please try add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
function blockusers_init() {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); var_dump( $current_user ->user_login ); exit; }  and tell me what you got as out put . * please post exact output.

Comment: Your code was redirecting all users. But the below code worked for me. 
`global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();
$username = $current_user->user_login;
if ( $username == 'John' ) {
    echo '';
} else {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this : First check if user is logged_in if yes then take the user information and do what ever you want with it

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      if($current_user->user_login == "John"){
             wp_safe_redirect("Where ever you want");
             exit;
           }
      else
          wp_safe_redirect(home_url('/'));
```

**NOTE** : Make sure to check your username in database , I set my username as my lastname.